# Entity Framework with multiple data sources

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is it possible to have an EDM that retrieves data from two data sources at the same time ? Say, it retrieves 3 tables from an SQL Server database and some other data from a binary file ?

Answer (score 5):

short answer: no

You could link database servers within your edmx main database and write views or stored procedures that access the data from the linked server tables.

Answer (score 3):

No, you'd need one EDMX per data source then use a repository to merge the results in memory.

Comment: Can you please point me to a link as to how to do this ? especially the results merging in memory.

Comment: Depends what you need to do but generally you get the results from both database queries and then assign them however you need in memory afterward. If you give a more specific question, we can give a more specific answer.

Comment: I have a EDM that exposes table1, table2 and table3. now, I have another API which will be used to retrieve data that will be used for table3. what I want is that when the client does this : var tb3 = context.table3.First(); =>it retrieves data from the API, but when he does this : var tb2 = context.table2.First(); => it retrieves data from table2 of the database.

Comment: You'd need one context per database but can then create a `repository` access class that has both contexts to return merged data from both where needed.